# Design table-like custom interface without UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I want to create an interface with the look and feel of a table. (e.g. somewhat similar to http://stephenmartin.me/iphone-form-field-design-patterns)

My app is going to display a form with labels/textboxes/buttons

I do not want to use UITable, but want to do using custom views (labels/textboxes)

Could someone provide help or any resources on how I can acheive this.

Basically the look and feel of the form should be elegant like a Table view.

What fonts are used for UITableView?

#### Upate:

Using a UITableView, I am not able to completely customize the look and feel. like adding buttons, textbox, etc

That is the reason I am looking for a custom view design.

Comment: Might I ask why you don't want to use UITableView? You just need to change the style to `UITableViewStyleGrouped` and you'll have the look that you are after...

Comment: Why don't you want to use a UITableView? You can create custom UITableViewCells that will achieve exactly the effect you're after.

Comment: That post is dated into the future! :O

Comment: @BoltClock Spooky. As the blog's tagline is "Reporting Live from the Mobile UX Trenches" this can only mean that Stephen Martin is ***FROM*** the future. We should try to hit him up for some horse racing results or something. :-)

Comment: There's absolutely no reason not to use `UITableView`. Seriously, you do 10 times more work trying to invent all the logic that's already been invented for the basic table view structure when all you really want is to add some new features. There are plenty of examples and—I'm sure—questions on SO about how to create custom table view cells with buttons, switches, etc.

Comment: Actually I am not reinventing the wheel..The reason being, I do not need any of the functionalities of UITableView. I just need the look-and-feel somewhat similar to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  UITableview.   You can completely customize the contents of every UITableViewCell.   Trust me, I used to avoid UITableView because I didn't understand it when I got started with iPhone programming, and it was *much more* work to create and place all those buttons, and to change their style one by one in Interface Builder when the spec changed, than just learning UITableview and customizing it properly.   UITableView is your *friend* on the iPhone.   Again, UITableView is *good*, learn it, love it, use it.   You can create custom UITableViewCells in interface builder, place text boxes, buttons, images, just about anything you can imagine.  And in doing so you'll learn more about how .xib files and objective C objects work together, boosting your skills as a developer.

edit: here's one result from googling "custom uitableviewcell" there are many others

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/

Comment: Could you point me to some examples of how UITableViewCells can be customized and the look/feel that I can acheive using the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this library to simplify your task:

http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/